# Comment templates to provide to new users or users who need a reminder

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, big-list

[This](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/how-to-welcome-someone-to-our-site) post inspired to start a comment template thread for Bio. Many SE sites make use of type of thread to added new and experienced users alike to provide clear, constructive comments to users who may not know all the site rules, norms, or customs.

### Welcoming inexperienced users

Welcome to Biology! Please have a look at [our site tour page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) which is filled with useful information on asking, answering, voting, and accepting answers. Additionally, we have a [help center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) which covers the most common questions you may face.

```
Welcome to Biology! Please have a look at 
[our site tour page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) 
which is filled with useful information on asking, answering, 
voting, and accepting answers. Additionally, we have a [help] 
which covers the most common questions you may face.
```

### Answers which are not answers

**Follow up questions:**

Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions are more than welcome! Please, however, use the "[Ask Question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

```
Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to 
repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions are more than welcome! 
Please, however, use the "[Ask]" link for your new question; there you can 
link to this question to provide the background.
```

**Thank you answers not OP**

Instead of posting a "Thank you" as an additional answer, you should give feedback clicking the 'up' arrow you can see above each answer's score. Once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [upvote answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to contribute to this score. We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

```
Instead of posting a "Thank you" as an additional answer, you should give 
feedback clicking the 'up' arrow you can see above each answer's score. Once 
you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [upvote 
answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to contribute to 
this score. We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so 
this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.
```

**Thank you answer by OP**

Instead of posting a "Thank you" as an additional answer, you should thank the answerer by upvoting their answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the check mark ✓). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

```
Instead of posting a "Thank you" as an additional answer, you should thank 
the answerer by upvoting their answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left 
of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it 
(by clicking on the check mark ✓). We want to keep the answer space reserved 
for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.
```

### Problem Statement Question with no effort

In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/asking) page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution or showing research. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

```
In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please 
take a look at the [How to Ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/asking) 
page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. 
This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting 
a solution or showing research. If you have questions about what to do or if 
you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification 
using the `add comment` function.
```

### How to ask homework questions

In your question's current form, it may not receive many answers. Please take a look at our [homework policy faq](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Here you will find information on how to improve your homework question so your fellow users will be more inclined to help. Thank you.

```
In your question's current form, it may not receive many answers. 
Please take a look at our [homework policy faq](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). 
Here you will find information on how to improve your homework question so your 
fellow users will be more inclined to help. Thank you.
```

### Question put on hold/closed

Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You should try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen it. Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.

```
Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) 
should give an explanation why. You should try to [edit] your question to 
address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review 
queue, where users can vote to reopen it. Therefore it would be good to 
avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the 
next edit.
```

### Multiple questions in one post

Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold.

`Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold.

### Please convert comment to an answer

@... Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered queue.

`@... Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered queue.`

---

Some of the comment templates are modifications of TeX.SE templates and some are verbatim since they seem to be universal. Their templates can be found [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks). Additionally, I have pulled a few from Math.SE [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) as well.

Feel free to update, add, or reword as anyone feels necessary.

Comment: Relevant: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) It's a userscript/addon that allows you to insert comments from a list of prepared ones.

Comment: @terdon feel free to add this to the post with a possible explanation on use in case others would like to incorporate it in their SE repertoire.